# Dataset for data mining project

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

I am searching for some datasets in form of 0 and 1 . i cant find dataset. i have find some 10 to 12 records but  want at least 100 records and 8 different records. 
This is one i have searched this [link](http://searchbusinessanalytics.techtarget.com/feature/Simple-data-mining-examples-and-datasets) but this is very low data http://searchbusinessanalytics.techtarget.com/feature/Simple-data-mining-examples-and-datasets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [UCI machine learning repository](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.html). There you can filter how many attributes/features or prediction classes you want and choose a dataset.

The `Credit Approval` dataset might suit your search criteria:

http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Credit+Approval

Also there is a dataset called `Mushroom dataset` which should also fit to what you are looking for.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, you may check the following link for a list of UCI datasets:
http://www.sgi.com/tech/mlc/db/

Answer (score 4):

Check out [public data sets from Google](http://www.google.com/publicdata/directory).  Maybe they'll have what you want.