# A data set for machine learning that has something to do with education

Tags: machine-learning

I am about to embark on a ML project for a class, and I would like to do something like a 'recommender system' for education (i.e. a system that says what the student ought to do next)

To elaborate further: It would be interesting to construct (some sort of) a system that can predict student accuracy, and try to recommend content that might increase that accuracy (in, say, math problems).

Now, I don't have a firm project in mind yet. I don't have the means to to data collection right now, so I would like to look at the data available in order to elaborate the project. Any dataset relating to education could be useful (and/or inspiring)

I found some interesting data sets for training ML here in stack overflow:
[Netflix Prize Dataset to be analyzed with Collaborative Filtering (CF) algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8770316/dataset-comparable-to-netflix-prize-for-playing-around/8770389#8770389) ,
[Dataset for data mining project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185217/dataset-for-data-mining-project?rq=1) but unfortunately nothing relating to education, as far as I could tell

Answer (score 3):

[UCI](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/index.html) is a great source of machine learning datasets

There is  a publicaly avaliable dataset for Teaching Assistant's evaluation which could suit your needs:

http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Teaching+Assistant+Evaluation

> **Collector**:
>
> Wei-Yin Loh (Department of Statistics, UW-Madison)
>
> **Donor**:
>
> Tjen-Sien Lim (limt '@' stat.wisc.edu)
>
> **Data Set Information**:
>
> The data consist of evaluations of teaching performance over three
>   regular semesters and two summer semesters of 151 teaching assistant
>   (TA) assignments at the Statistics Department of the University of
>   Wisconsin-Madison. The scores were divided into 3 roughly equal-sized
>   categories ("low", "medium", and "high") to form the class variable.
>
> **Attribute Information**:
>
> 1. Whether of not the TA is a native English speaker (binary); 1=English speaker, 2=non-English speaker
> 2. Course instructor (categorical, 25 categories)
> 3. Course (categorical, 26 categories)
> 4. Summer or regular semester (binary) 1=Summer, 2=Regular
> 5. Class size (numerical)
> 6. Class attribute (categorical) 1=Low, 2=Medium, 3=High

Answer (score 0):

In the machine learning class we took, we did competition with the shared tasks in CONLL. There are lots of different types of learning set available and we formed in teams to compete with each others.

Another place to look for dataset is kaggle (http://www.kaggle.com/competitions). There are different types of dataset and they are fun as well.

Answer (score 0):

My choice turn out to be https://pslcdatashop.web.cmu.edu/ (a site speciallised in data in educational settings)

In particular, they hosted a KDD cup in 2010, in which the challenge was to predict student accuracy given previous performance: https://pslcdatashop.web.cmu.edu/KDDCup/rules_evaluation.jsp

It is a rather big dataset, and you can also see the papers of the people who participated (and that is quite useful!)